Prescribed Euler class
Let $X$ be some nice topological space (e.g. paracompact, CW complex, etc.). A classical problem in algebraic topology is to realize a given cohomology class $x\in H^k(X;\mathbb Z)$ as characteristic classes, for example, the Euler class.
Let $E_k(X)=\{x\in H^k(X;\mathbb Z)|\ \exists$ real bundle $\xi:E\to X,$ s.t. $e(\xi)=x\}$.
In general, $E_k(X)\neq H^k(X;\mathbb Z)$, for example, $E_3(\mathbb RP^3)=0\subset H^3(\mathbb RP^3;\mathbb Z)=\mathbb Z$ (see here, Proposition 3.1). For $k$ even, it is known that $2N(k,n)\cdot x\in E_k(X)$ if $X$ is an $n$-dimensional CW complex (Theorem 1.3). Also, similar result holds for Pontryagin class (see here, Lemma B.1).
Now consider $k$ odd. It's well known $e(\xi)=-e(\xi)$ by the Thom isomorphism and commutativity relation for cup product. In this case, $e(\xi)$ can be nontrivial, for example here.
$\textbf{My question}$: For $k$ odd and $x\in H^k(X;\mathbb Z)$ any 2-torsion element. Does $x\in E_k(X)$ ? If not always, can anyone give some counterexample?
It is known that all torsion in $H^*(G_n;\mathbb Z)$ has order two. Can we use this fact and something like spliting principle to prove that?

Hi Ted, I answered your question two days ago, but the original version of my answer contained an error as pointed out by Michael Albanese. I have fixed everything and this (correct) version should give you a bunch of examples of non-realizable classes. (I'm writing this comment to notify the change as the OP wouldn't be able to receive notification otherwise.)

@Kevin.S Yes, thanks very much!

Here is a counterexample. Consider $X=\Sigma\Bbb RP^4$ which has cohomology $H^3(X;\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z_2$. Let $\xi:E\to X$ be a rank $3$ oriented real vector bundle. We have the following constraints on the Euler class.

$e(\xi)=w_3(\xi)\mod 2$.
$Sq^2(w_3(\xi))=w_2(\xi)w_3(\xi)=0$ since $X$ is a suspension.

Therefore, we must have $(Sq^2\circ \rho_\ast)(e(\xi))=0$, where $\rho:\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z_2$ is the reduction of coefficient.
Suppose $e(\xi)\neq 0$. Then $\rho_\ast(e(\xi))$ is the generator of $H^3(X;\Bbb Z_2)$ since the reduction of coefficient induces an isomorphism. Also, using the suspension isomorphism and the fact that Steenrod operations are stable, one can deduce that $(Sq^2\circ \rho_\ast)(e(\xi))$ generates $H^5(X;\Bbb Z_2)$. This is clearly a contradiction.
The conclusion is that the non-zero element in $H^3(X;\Bbb Z)\cong\Bbb Z_2$ cannot be realized as the Euler class of real vector bundles.

More generally, let $n\ge 1$, and consider $X=\Sigma^{2n-1}\Bbb RP^{4}$. The same argument shows that $E_{2n+1}(X)=\{0\}$. The reason is that the cup products in $X$ are trivial, so Wu formula reduces to $Sq^2(w_{2n+1})=0$, but $Sq^2:H^{2n+1}(X;\Bbb Z_2)\to H^{2n+3}(X;\Bbb Z_2)$ is an isomorphism due to stability of Steenrod squares, so $w_{2n+1}(\xi)=0$ for any rank $(2n+1)$ bundle $\xi$ over $X$. For oriented bundles, the relation between $e(\xi)$ and $w_{2n+1}(\xi)$ implies that $e(\xi)=0$ as coefficient reduction induces an isomorphism.
